# Where are the Subsonic T4 templates when installed through NuGet?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, nuget, nuget-package

This might be a dumb question, but I just integrated Subsonic to an ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms project and while the dll reference was added, I don't see the T4 templates anywhere.

I *think* that the T4 templates are not required if you're using the SimpleRepository approach, but I don't really see the sense in making Subsonic a NuGet package if you're not getting the T4 templates with it. I'd think it'd be rather more logical if the Subsonic NuGet package installed the T4 templates and the user just removes them if he doesn't need them, rather than having to download the T4 templates separately even though you installed Subsonic through NuGet.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to add them in but the problem is (according to David Ebbo) that the reference drops right into the /bin folder. The T4s, however, need to go into the root somewhere because you need to add the code to the project.

I know it's an inconvenience - but there was no manifesting system (not sure if there is one now) to use that would say "push this into the root".

If it changes, I'll update the package :).

Comment: Just found out that NuGet comes with a bit of a manifest now - whether I can do something about the T4s... I don't know.

Comment: Rob, email me about this and I'll help you out. If you need them to go into the root of the project, it's very easy. In your NuGet package, put them in a folder named "Content".

Comment: Thanks Phil!! Rob, I'll be waiting for the updated package :) whenever you manage to have some spare time of course. Thank you both guys.

Comment: As of today, the T4 templates are not put into the project. They're in the packages folder.